# What applications will be broken on Ubuntu 14.04 to upgrade Bluez from 4.x to the latest 5.x?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, bluetooth

Ubuntu 14.04 is still using Bluez 4.x which is unfriendly to BLE (bluetooth low energy). I would like to upgrade to the latest Bluez 5.x but worried about the impact. What will be the problems, if any, if the upgrade is done?

Comment: I don't see why there would be any.

Comment: I think some apps with UI that helps user do pairing will be affected because they use the existing Bluetooth stack.

Comment: If there is an upgrade available for it using `apt-get upgrade`, then it's safe.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option is not available. Have to compile from source code. THis is why I asked this question.

Comment: Oh. Is it the version for 15.04?